# Riverpod: How to convert WidgetRef to Ref?

Tags: flutter, riverpod

I was creating an application where, I need to call a function, which will take Ref as input (as it can be called by the providers), but I also need to call it using WidgetRef, while listening to a StateNotifier Provider.

```dart
final firstProvider = ... //Initialization

final someProvider = Provider<String>((ref) {
  performOperation(ref);
  return '';
});

class MyWidget extends ConsumerWidget {
...

  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    ref.listen(firstProvider, (pref, next) => performOperation(ref));
    return ...;
  }
}
```

Where the `performOperation` function might be like this:-

```dart
void performOperation(Ref ref) {
  final value = ref.read(...);
  final secondValue = genSecondValue(value);
  ref.read(countProvider).increment(value);
  ref.read(secondCountProvider).increment(secondValue);
}
```

I do realize this is not allowed, to update the state of a provider, while initializing a provider, so can anyone suggest what would be the appropriate method to refactor this code?

I want to update the value of `countProvider` and `secondProvider` whenever we read the `someProvider` and the state of `firstProvider` changes.

Comment: To begin with, calling `performOperation` inside your provider like you did sounds like an anti-pattern. I'd have to see what that function does, but chances are it's doing something bad.

Comment: @RémiRousselet Let's assume that `performOperation` , increment the value of a `countProvider` (StateProvider), as I want to increment the value of `countProvider` whenever the `someProvider` is read, or whenever the value of `firstProvider` is updated.
I did realize that this is not allowed, to update the value of a provider while initializing one. So can you recommend a design for how you would refactor the code here?

Comment: @RémiRousselet I have updated the question accordingly

Comment: Your updated `performOperation`is 100% bad. By doing so, someProvider is modifying other providers while initializing. That's not allowed.

Comment: @RémiRousselet That is why I asked to suggest any refactoring that can be done, according to the requirements I mentioned in the question.

Comment: It's hard to say. I doubt you're making counters. What you're trying to do most likely is different from what you shared.