# How to pass different Riverpod Ref types to a callback?

Tags: flutter, state, flutter-provider, riverpod

I will omit any code here, as this question is rather conceptual.
I'm currently developing a Flutter App using [riverpod](https://riverpod.dev/docs/introduction/why_riverpod) to manage the components of the app-wide state, such as session tokens, etc.

I thus have methods which require access to the current riverpod state. I initially thought that this can be achieved by passing a variable of type `Ref` to every callback requiring any data stored within any Provider. Yet it seems that this is not really possible, as there's the `ProviderRef`, `WidgetRef`, `Ref`, etc. Using any of these types as the type of the according function parameter will not lead to correct code, e.g.:

- Say you have coded a wrapper method you use to execute HTTP API Requests in your app. Let's call that method `send(Ref providerReference)`, for simplicity.
- When you want to use this method e.g. to initialize a provider, this works.
- When you try to use this method within a `ConsumerWidget`, it will not work; as your `send()` function expects a `Ref`, but you actually have a `WidgetRef` within your `ConsumerWidget`.
- The same problem goes for the other way around.

So before simply transforming my `send(Ref providerReference)` into `sendWithoutWidgetRef(Ref providerReference)` and `sendWithWidgetRef(WidgetRef providerReference)`, I just wondered if there's anything I'm misunderstanding regarding the use in that sense of riverpod?

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73786174/riverpod-how-to-convert-widgetref-to-ref) has some kind of a similar context, but provides no real solution.

I know you could of course pass all the different kinds of providers to your `send()` method, e.g. do sth like `send(AppLanguageProvider langRef,SessionTokenProvider sessionRef, ....)`, but requiring to fetch all these providers before calling `send()`, every single time you call `send()`, feels odd to me and kind of defeats the purpose of even using a provider. In that case it may be simple to store the current app language + session token in something like [Flutter Secure Storage](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_secure_storage), and not even use riverpod at all.

So I really think that I'm misunderstanding something?

Comment: [Why is there no shared interface between Ref and WidgetRef?](https://riverpod.dev/docs/essentials/faq#why-is-there-no-shared-interface-between-ref-and-widgetref)

Comment: Yes I know but everything I understood from that is "Such code should be refactored to always use Ref.", and "You should not try to read providers from anywhere" from [here](https://github.com/rrousselGit/riverpod/issues/295). I still don't get it, does this mean that you should create a Provider class whenever methods require access to provider data from outside widgets? Hence the class with the HTTP API Request wrapper `send()` method should actually be transformed into a provider itself (`keepAlive : false`) ?

Comment: Most likely your `send` method should belong to a Notifier. You can think of what the `send` method actually does and what kind of object should be exposed by the Notifier it's tied with.

Comment: That‘s the thing I can‘t think of sny object / state for it, it‘s really only for the access of the state variables when sending a request, so doing a Notifier with thus empty build() feels wrong?

Comment: If you have observable state with mutators, use the notifier classes.  If you have no need for mutators, use FutureProvider, StreamProvider, or Provider.  Provider is also useful for lazy singletons that might need access to Ref.